# Ruby on Rails: bbc-code and performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bbcode

I am using bb-code in a Rails application for postings and comments. At the moment, I have the following to put a post's content in a view:

```
<%= @post.content.bbcode_to_html.html_safe.gsub('<a', '<a rel="nofollow"') %>
```

What is the best way to convert the bb-code to html and add "nofollow" to all links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bb-ruby` gem you are using allows for using custom BBCode translations passed as parameters to the `bbcode_to_html` method. However, if you really want **ALL** links to contain the `rel="nofollow"`, I think your best bet is going to be monkey patching them gem itself. Based on the [BBRuby source](https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/bb-ruby/blob/master/lib/bb-ruby.rb), you want to do this:

```rb
module BBRuby
  @@tags = @@tags.merge({
    'Link' => [
      /\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/mi,
      '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\2</a>',
      'Hyperlink to somewhere else',
      'Maybe try looking on [url=http://google.com]Google[/url]?',
      :link],
    'Link (Implied)' => [
      /\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/mi,
      '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\1</a>',
      'Hyperlink (implied)',
      "Maybe try looking on [url]http://google.com[/url]",
      :link],
    'Link (Automatic)' => [
      /(\A|\s)((https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<]+)/,
      ' <a href="\2" rel="nofollow">\2</a>',
      'Hyperlink (automatic)',
      'Maybe try looking on http://www.google.com',
      :link]
    })
end
```

This will rewrite the BBRuby translator to always include a nofollow attribute. I would put this in `config/initializers` with a descriptive filename such as `bbruby_nofollow_monkeypatch.rb`

As for the `html_safe`, I would leave that as is. As I understand it that is a preferred way of doing it and in my opinion it keeps your intent clear. The above monkey patch makes the line in your view more readable:

```
<%= @post.content.bbcode_to_html.html_safe %>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! As I am still quite new to Rails, it is interesting to see how monkey patching of gems is possible.

Comment: Not a problem, but just so you know you have to manually award me the bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty